# Python packages not installing in any sys.path directory

Tags: python, django, pythonpath, sys.path

I see there are questions that are somewhat related to this one, but their answers don't help me clarify my doubt. Please note that this is not about how to successfully import django, it's about the differences between folders and why an installation fell in a specific directory.

I installed django via pip, just as I have installed other packages, but I realized it installed in a directory that's not in any sys.path directory. Specifically, it installed in "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0\Lib\site-packages". Actually, other packages I have installed are there, but they're also in "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages", which is in the sys.path list. I don't know why django was installed in that directory. I added that path as an environment variable but I still couldn't import it. Oddly, I could run `!django-admin startproject` and it created a new project, but nothing else could be run.

I managed to import django successfully by doing `sys.path.append()`, but my questions remain.

Why did django install there? What is the difference between these two directories? Is there a way to control this when I do the next package installation? Why did `!django-admin startproject` run if it couldn't import it?

Thank you.

Comment: _I added that path as an environment variable but I still couldn't import it._ That shouldn't be necessary though, no? You are using Conda environments?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Spyder. And well, I did it after reading somewhere that it could be that, and after reading the ImportError message "Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?". I see I forgot to say that this is when I try to run these commands from my python shell instead of the command line, from where I get no error. Probably that would help get the answer.

Comment: Are you activating the environment correctly? Where did you install the packages? Why install them with pip in the first place?

Comment: So, is it imperative to do it in a virtual environment? Why not use pip? That one got me, could you please explain to me like I'm 5 years old?

Comment: Well, I've now read that ´python manage.py runserver´  (which is when the import fails) is only possible after ´source virtualenvname/bin/acivate´, which answers that question. Now the question would be why. And the original questions remain.

Comment: _So, is it imperative to do it in a virtual environment?_ No, but what is important is knowing where packages are going, which Python installation is being used, etc. _Why not use pip?_ It's best to use Conda for installing packages inside of a Conda environment.

Comment: Okay, I see now. About where I installed the packages, I thought they were going to be installed in some sort of default directory, but then I realized they were here "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0\Lib\site-packages", instead of "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages", which is was originally in the sys.path list. I honestly didn't know I should specify installation paths to pip.

Comment: _I honestly didn’t know I should specify installation paths to pip._ I’m not entirely sure you need to. I use Conda, and I never mess around with installation paths.

Comment: Well, I never did and django installed in that directory for some reason. Isn't it supposed to install in a directory that's in sys.path by default?

Comment: _Isn't it supposed to install in a directory that's in sys.path by default?_ I'm not familiar with the specifics, but that would certainly defeat the purpose of using virtual environments, no?

Comment: Yeah, now that I'm reading about virtual environments, it makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for your help. I think now I can learn some more things with this information.

Comment: You're going to need to remove whatever you added to your PATH, and possibly reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: Why would it be necessary to reinstall?

Comment: You might have accidentally broken/corrupted the install in some way. It’s really just to be safe.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I'll then schedule the reinstallation.